# How to delete master detail row in Oracle APEX?

Tags: oracle-apex, master-detail

I have a master detail form (drill down) in Oracle APEX. So, when I want to delete one row in master form, I have to firstly delete the detail rows (which I have in that master row) and only then I can delete the master row. It's not practical for my end users. Is there any way possible that I can delete whole master row with all detail rows included in one step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with APEX, it is the definition of your foreign key constraint between master and child table that determines the behavior. In particular there is an "ON DELETE" clause that has "NO ACTION" as default. That implies that you cannot delete the master row if there are child rows. Define the foreign key with an "ON DELETE CASCADE" clause so the child rows get deleted as well. Check the documentation for more info.